# Ionic app CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present, using Lumen API with CORS middleware

Tags: javascript, php, api, ionic-framework, http-headers

I am building an app which uses a Lumen API. On the Lumen project I have two files which I found on the internet whilst looking up how to handle CORS in Lumen.

CorsMiddleware.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
class CorsMiddleware {
  public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
  {
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return $response;
  }
}
```

CatchAllOptionsRequestsProvider.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
/**
* If the incoming request is an OPTIONS request
* we will register a handler for the requested route
*/

class CatchAllOptionsRequestsProvider extends ServiceProvider {
  public function register()
  {
    $request = app('request');
    if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
    {
      app()->options($request->path(), function() { return response('', 200); });
    }
  }
}
```

These two files fixed my initial CORS issue. I am able to perform a GET and receive data from the API. But when I try a POST method to the API I once again get the following error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access."

Upon inspecting the network tab in chrome, There are two requests. The first is an OPTIONS request, which I believe is just to get the allowed headers from the server. The second request is my POST request with the correct payload. They both return a status code of 200 OK but I still get the Access-Control error mentioned above.

**It works when using POSTMAN to send data to my API, but not when I use Ionic Serve in the browser**

For those who are wondering, I am using Ionic's $http method for the call:

```
    MORE CODE.......
    var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: APIUrl + 'register',
      timeout: timeout.promise,
      data: {"name": "Michael"}
    }

    $http(req).then(function(res) {
    .......MORE CODE
```

Might it be something to do with the server apache config? I have mod_rewrite enabled.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in control of the server, you might need to set the required headers there. Depending on which server, this might help: 
http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Yes I'm in control if it. I will give that a look and let you know of my progress. Thanks!

Comment: I added to <Directory /var/www/> in apache2.conf so it now reads:
<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
and now it works! Thanks a lot. I was looking for help on this for over a day and it only just occurred to me that it might be a server config issue. Is there a security risk with this header or is it ok for the live version once it is done?

Comment: You're welcome. You can specify domain for Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" when your application goes live.

Comment: Ah ok. So for example change <Directory /var/www/> to <Directory /var/www/path/to/my/lumen/project>?